# How to extract a substring from a filename (which is the date) when reading a file in Azure Data Factory v2?

Tags: date, substring, filenames, azure-data-factory

I have this Pipeline where I'm trying to process a CSV file with client data. This file is located in an Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1, and it consists of client data from a certain period of time (i.e. from January 2019 to July 2019). Therefore, the file name would be something like *"Clients_20190101_20190731.csv"*.

From my Data Factory v2, I would like to read the file name and the file content to validate that the content (or a date column specifically) actually matches the range of dates of the file name.

So the question is: how can I read the file name, extract the dates from the name, and use them to validate the range of dates inside the file?

Comment: Add the filename to the input columns in the Copy Task using the new `$$filepath` as described here: [Add additional columns during copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-overview#add-additional-columns-during-copy).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but you should be able to use the get metadata activity to get the filename. Then you can access the outputs of the metadata activity and build an expression to split out the file name.  If you want to validate data in the file based on the metadata output (filename expression you built) your option would be to use Mapping Data Flows or to pass in the expression to a Databricks Notebook. Mapping Data Flows uses Databricks under the hood. ADF natively does not have transformation tools that you could accomplish this. You can't look at the data in the file except to move it (COPY activity).  With the exception of the lookup activity which has a 5000 record limit.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity